# The number of symmetric polynomials of n degree

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

How many symmetric polynomials of n degree with all their coefficients $\ =1 $ are there?Is there a type that computes their number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of different symmetric *monomials* of degree $n$ in $k$ variables with all the coefficients 1 is equal to the number $p(n,k)$ of partitions of $n$ in up to $k$ parts, for every such partition say $a_1+a_2+\dots + a_k = n$ with $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \dots \ge a_k \ge 0$ we have the symmetric "*monomial*":
  $$ x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2} \dots x_k^{a_k} + \dots $$

The number of different symmetric *homogeneous* polynomials of degree $n$ in $k$ variables 
with all the coefficients 1 is as a consequence  $ 2^{p(n,k)}-1 $

The number of different symmetric polynomials of degree (exactly) $n$ in $k$ variables 
with all the coefficients 1 is then
  $$ (2^{p(n,k)}-1)2^{p(n-1,k)+p(n-2,k)+ \dots+ p(1,k)+p(0,k)} $$

So if you write 
  $$P(n,k) = p(n,k) + p(n-1,k)+ \dots +p(0,k) $$
the number of partitions of numbers up to $n$ in at most $k$ parts then the number you ask for (if I have understood the question and I haven't made a silly mistake is)
  $$ 2^{P(n,k)} -2^{P(n-1,k)} $$
EDIT: This was wrong. Sorry.

EDIT 2: The answer above is answering the question if we consider the *total degree* of the symmetric functions, in view of the comments we are looking instead for polynomials with largest degree $n$ in any of the variables then we have the following:

1. The number of different symmetric monomials with degree up to $n$ in all the variables is $n^k$.
2. The total number of symmetric polynomials composed with this monomials is $2^{n^k}$.
3. So the number of symmetric polynomials having at least one term of degree $n$ in one of the variables is
   $$ 2^{n^k}-2^{(n-1)^k} $$

Comment: It seems that something went wrong with my question.When I said degree n i meant the higher degree of one (so of all) invariant .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by invariant, do you mean homogenous?, all the terms have the same total degree? take this four examples with $n=3$ and $k=2$, a) $x^3+y^3$, b) $x^2y + xy^2$, c) $x^3+y^3 + x + y$ d) $x^2y + xy^2+x+y$, which are you counting as degree 3?

Comment: i mean the cases a) and c)

Comment: many thanks for your time.